# Why is my sqlite3 program saying "column not found"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, discord, discord.py

I want to make a levelling system for my Discord bot. I imported `datetime` and `sqlite3`:

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member): ###add a row in the db for the new member when they join
   user = member.id
   conn = sqlite3.connect('level.db')
   cur = conn.cursor()
   cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS levels INSERT INTO levels("userid", "xp", "level")VALUES(user, 0, 0)')
   conn.commit()
   conn.close()
   await member.send("Welcome '{user.mention}'!")
 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    user = message.author.id
    conn = sqlite3.connect('level.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT xp, level FROM levels WHERE userid = ?')
    results = cur.fetchone()
    row = results[0] ### results will be a list and since you're only fetching one record in this instance, you only need the first index
    old_xp = row[0] ##the first item in the index, in this case, xp
    old_level = row[1] ## the second item in the index, in this case, level
    new_xp = old_xp + 1
    if new_xp == 25: #this is where you set the threshold for leveling up to the first level
        new_level = 1
    else:
        new_level = old_level
    ###add more logic here for successive level-ups
    cur.execute('UPDATE levels SET xp = ?, level = ? WHERE userid = ?', (new_xp, new_level, user))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Output :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/achourishi799/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/achourishi799/ouiudusfd/main.py", line 49, in on_message
    cur.execute('SELECT xp, level FROM levels WHERE userid = ?')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: userid
```

Keep explanations simple please.

Comment: Do you actually have a column with that name in your database table...? You can't insert something into a column that doesn't exist, and the error message suggests it doesn't.

Comment: When I try to run your `CREATE TABLE` query, is raises `OperationalError: near "INSERT": syntax error`.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is with the table creation:

```
In [1]: import sqlite3

In [2]: conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
Out[2]: <sqlite3.Connection at 0x8738a53f0>

In [3]: cur = conn.cursor()
Out[3]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x873faa340>

In [4]: cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS levels INSERT INTO levels("userid", "xp", "level")VALUES(
   ...: user, 0, 0)')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b1dd55196e6d> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS levels INSERT INTO levels("userid", "xp", "level")VALUES(user, 0, 0)')

OperationalError: near "INSERT": syntax error
```

Note that `execute` can only execute a single SQL statement.

The following works:

```
In [5]: cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS levels (userid, xp, level)')
Out[5]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x873faa340>

In [6]: cur.execute('INSERT INTO levels VALUES ("user", 0, 0)')
Out[6]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x873faa340>

In [7]: conn.commit()

In [8]: cur.execute("SELECT * FROM levels").fetchall()
Out[8]: [('user', 0, 0)]
```

The second problem is with the select query:

```
In [16]: cur.execute('SELECT xp, level FROM levels WHERE userid = ?')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b497d02f64c3> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 cur.execute('SELECT xp, level FROM levels WHERE userid = ?')

ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

You are not supplying an argument for `execute` to use in the query.

Use something like this instead:

```
In [17]: cur.execute('SELECT xp, level FROM levels WHERE userid = ?', ("user",)).fetchone()
Out[17]: (0, 0)
```

**Edit1:**

If you have an existing file `level.db`, you can inspect it using the `sqlite3` command-line tool.

Use the `.dump` command to show the definition of the `levels` table:

```
> sqlite3 levels.db
-- Loading resources from /home/rsmith/.sqliterc
SQLite version 3.39.3 2022-09-05 11:02:23
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
> .tables
levels
> .dump levels
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE levels (userid, xp, level);
INSERT INTO levels VALUES('user',0,0);
COMMIT;
> SELECT * FROM levels;
userid  xp  level
------  --  -----
user    0   0
```

Comment: So I followed your commands and I am still getting the same issue:

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` will (unsurprisingly) only create the table if it does not already exist.  It sounds like the table _does_ already exist, in an earlier version that does not contain the `userid` column.

Comment: @AaravChourishi Inspect the existing database file as shown in **Edit1**. That will show you the existing column names.

Comment: Ok so I checked the tables and instead of 'userid' its 'user' but now im getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/achourishi799/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/achourishi799/ouiudusfd/main.py", line 60, in on_message
    row = results[0] ### results will be a list and since you're only fetching one record in this instance, you only need the first index
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @AaravChourishi This is a typical error if `results` is `None`.